# Actions class throws JavascriptException when using latest version of chrome (chrome 91)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I have a selenium webdriver (java) test developed for a salesforce application, in which I get the following error when using Actions class

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error

The code is simple,

```
WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(searchIcon).clickAndHold(searchIcon).release(searchIcon).build().perform();
```

At third line, I get the exception. It was working fine before with previous versions of chrome. It is currently working fine on FF.

Comment: wait for stable chromedriver, meanwhile you can try beta version for chrome 91

Comment: Thanks, I did not update chrome myself, it was an auto update : Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Are you leaving something out here?  Why not just element.click()?

Comment: element.click() also gives the same issue, basically, any Actions class function throws this Exception. This is just an example that was used for a specific element which is not clicked with just element.click();